# How to implement modalBottomSheet with dynamic height and scrolling part?

Tags: flutter, dart

This is second day I try to implement modalBottomSheet, which would adjust it's height to list of elements and above those list has not scrolling part. Number of elements and it's size is not constant.

This is my current code which adjust height perfectly and doesn't show empty space in sheet, but looks like Wrap doesnt allow scroll and ListView is not scrollable at all.

I also tried replacing Wrap with Column with mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min, but when I do that, ListView requires expanded and then bottomModalSheet takes whole screen which is something I definitely don't want. I would like to not setting size of ListView children, because it's not constant

```
 showModalBottomSheet(
    isScrollControlled: true,
    context: context,
    builder: (context) => Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
      child: Wrap(
        //  mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        alignment: WrapAlignment.center,
        children: [
          Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
            SizedBox(
                height: 300,
                child: Image.memory(
                  emoji.imageData,
                )),
            Text(emoji.name),
          ]),
          ListView.builder(
            shrinkWrap: true,
            itemCount: moods.length,
            itemBuilder: (context, i) => Column(children: [
              const Divider(),
              Row(
                children: [
                  Column(
                    mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                    children: [
                      Text(
                          '${moods[i].dateTime.day} ${returnMonth(moods[i].dateTime)}'),
                      Text(dateTimeToHourMinute(
                          dateTime: moods[i].dateTime, context: context)),
                    ],
                  ),
                  spacer,
                  IconButton(
                      icon: const Icon(
                        Icons.more_horiz,
                      ),
                      onPressed: () {
                        showRemoveMoodDialog(context, moods[i]);
                      }),
                ],
              ),
              if (moods[i].note.isNotEmpty)
                Padding(
                  padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                  child: Text(moods[i].note),
                ),
            ]),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 1):

The issue you're facing is due to the fact that `Wrap` and `Column` widgets do not support scrolling. `ListView` does support scrolling, but it needs to be given a specific height to work properly inside a `BottomSheet`.

One way to solve this is to use a `SingleChildScrollView` for the non-scrolling part and a `ListView` for the scrolling part. You can use a `ConstrainedBox` to limit the maximum height of the `BottomSheet`.

Here's how you can modify your code:

```
showModalBottomSheet(
  isScrollControlled: true,
  context: context,
  builder: (context) => Padding(
    padding: const EdgeInsets.all(20),
    child: ConstrainedBox(
      constraints: BoxConstraints(maxHeight: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height * 0.8), // Adjust this value as needed
      child: Column(
        mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
        children: [
          SingleChildScrollView(
            child: Stack(alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter, children: [
              SizedBox(
                  height: 300,
                  child: Image.memory(
                    emoji.imageData,
                  )),
              Text(emoji.name),
            ]),
          ),
          Expanded(
            child: ListView.builder(
              shrinkWrap: true,
              itemCount: moods.length,
              itemBuilder: (context, i) => Column(children: [
                const Divider(),
                Row(
                  children: [
                    Column(
                      mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.min,
                      children: [
                        Text(
                            '${moods[i].dateTime.day} ${returnMonth(moods[i].dateTime)}'),
                        Text(dateTimeToHourMinute(
                            dateTime: moods[i].dateTime, context: context)),
                      ],
                    ),
                    spacer,
                    IconButton(
                        icon: const Icon(
                          Icons.more_horiz,
                        ),
                        onPressed: () {
                          showRemoveMoodDialog(context, moods[i]);
                        }),
                  ],
                ),
                if (moods[i].note.isNotEmpty)
                  Padding(
                    padding: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 20.0),
                    child: Text(moods[i].note),
                  ),
              ]),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  ),
);
```

In this code, `ConstrainedBox` is used to limit the maximum height of the `BottomSheet`. `SingleChildScrollView` is used for the non-scrolling part, and `ListView` is used for the scrolling part. The `Expanded` widget makes the `ListView` take up all remaining space in the `BottomSheet`, allowing it to scroll.

Comment: I'm trying to avoid setting height - I want it to be dynamic, so if there is one note it shows only one note below not scrollable part and if there are 100 notes it shows on screen as much as possible

Comment: unfortunately, it is not even close to solution

Comment: To create a modal bottom sheet with dynamic height, you can use the `DraggableScrollableSheet` widget. This widget creates a portion of a sequence of user-generated actions that are scrolled, potentially moving child widgets in and out of view.